# Instance Variables in Javascript Classes

Tags: javascript, class, oop, constructor, instance-variables

I mostly code in PHP and Java, but I will occasionally work on the front end of a project and use JavaScript. I usually create objects differently than below, but I came across this and it caught my interest being that the syntax is similar to what I usually program in.

I was poking around, trying to figure out how to use instance variables in JavaScript classes using the syntax below. I've tried declaring the instance variables by `name;`, or `_name;`, or `var name;`, or all of those previous variables and adding `= null;`, but still get errors in my console. The errors are mostly `my-file.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. I'm just trying to set my instance variable through my constructor.

How do I use instance variables in JavaScript, using the syntax below?

```
class MyClass {
  var _name;

  constructor(name) {
    _name = name;
    alert("Hello world, from OO JS!");
    this.myFunction();
  }

  myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myElement").addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log("Ant's function runs. Hello!");
    });
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var person = "John Smith";
  var myClass = new MyClass(person);
}
```

Comment: Use the `this` keyword : `this._name = name;`

Comment: You don’t declare properties; just set `this._name = name;`.

Comment: @Ryan How would I then access the instance variable in my event listener? `this._name` just yields `undefined`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is still a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) and it would look as follows:

```
class A {
   property = "value";
}
```

BTW, when you want to access a class property (i.e. an own object property) you'll still need to use `this.property`:

```
class A {
    property = "value";

    constructor() {
        console.log(this.property);
    }
}
```

If you want to use this syntax today, you'll need to use a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/).

Answer (score 16):

You don’t declare properties; just set `this._name = name`.

> @Ryan How would I then access the instance variable in my event listener? `this._name` just yields `undefined`.

Each function call* runs with its own `this`; your event listener is a function. You can assign `var that = this;` outside the event listener and access `that` inside it:

```
myFunction() {
  var that = this;

  document.getElementById("myElement").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(that._name);
  });
}
```

Or create a new function that always calls yours with the same `this` using `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myElement").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(this._name);
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Or use ES6’s arrow functions, which use the value of `this` where they were defined (lexical `this`):

```
myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myElement").addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(this._name);
  });
}
```

Comment: Super helpful. Thanks for explaining.